# How to Create a recurring profile in PayPal advanced

Tags: paypal

I have already implemented recurring payments using paypal website payment statandards. The steps i followed are intial SetExpressCheckout-> GetExpresscheckout->DoExpressCheckout->CreateReccuringPayments Profile. The code is as follows SetExpressCheckout

```
public static PayPalRedirect ExpressCheckout()
    {
        NameValueCollection values = new NameValueCollection();

        values["METHOD"] = "SetExpressCheckout";
        values["RETURNURL"] = PayPalSettings.ReturnUrl;
        values["CANCELURL"] = PayPalSettings.CancelUrl;
        values["PAYMENTACTION"] = "Sale";
        values["CURRENCYCODE"] = "USD";
        values["BUTTONSOURCE"] = "XYZ";
        values["USER"] = PayPalSettings.Username;
        values["PWD"] = PayPalSettings.Password;
        values["SIGNATURE"] = PayPalSettings.Signature;
        values["SUBJECT"] = "";
        values["VERSION"] = "51.0";
        values["AMT"] = PayPalSettings.OrderAmount;
        values["L_BILLINGTYPE0"] = "RecurringPayments";
        values["L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0"] = "abcd";

        values = Submit(values);

        string ack = values["ACK"].ToLower();

        if (ack == "success" || ack == "successwithwarning")
        {
            return new PayPalRedirect
            {
                Token = values["TOKEN"],
                Url = String.Format("https://{0}/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token={1}",
                   PayPalSettings.CgiDomain, values["TOKEN"])
            };
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(values["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]);
        }
    }
```

OnSuccess the response will be hitting to my sucess url. There i created my recurring profile using the following code.

```
 public ActionResult Success(string token)
{
    bool isSuccess = false;
    GetExpressCheckout getExpressCheckout = new GetExpressCheckout();
    GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponseType getExpressCheckoutResponse = getExpressCheckout.ECGetExpressCheckoutCode(token);

    if (getExpressCheckoutResponse.Ack == AckCodeType.Success)
    {
        ExpressCheckout expressCheckout = new ExpressCheckout();
        DoExpressCheckoutPaymentResponseType doExpressCheckoutResponse = expressCheckout.DoExpressCheckoutPayment
                                                    (
                                                        token,
                                                        getExpressCheckoutResponse.GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponseDetails.PayerInfo.PayerID,
                                                        PayPalSettings.OrderAmount,
                                                        PaymentActionCodeType.Sale,
                                                        CurrencyCodeType.USD
                                                    );

        if (doExpressCheckoutResponse.Ack == AckCodeType.Success)
        {
            //create Recurring Payment Profile
            CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile createRecurringPaymentsProfile = new CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile();
            CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileResponseType recurringPaymentProfileResponse = createRecurringPaymentsProfile.CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileCode(
                                                                                            token,
                                                                                            doExpressCheckoutResponse.Timestamp.AddDays(7),
                                                                                            PayPalSettings.OrderAmount,
                                                                                            1,
                                                                                            BillingPeriodType.Week,
                                                                                            CurrencyCodeType.USD
                                                                                            );
            if (recurringPaymentProfileResponse.Ack == AckCodeType.Success)
            {
                //Transaction is successfull. 
                //insert record database
            }
        }
    }

   }
```

Everything works fine in the sandbox environment. When i move to live, my client said that this is not working in live mode. So on enquiry it is said that he has upgraded to PayPal advanced and the api credentials that i am using in live is paypal advanced business account. So my questions are:

1) Will my code works same as that with a paypal advanced credentials?
2) Do the steps for creating recurring profile same in paypal advanced? I need both paypal express checkout and credit card transaction for payment?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The steps will be slightly different.  A quick overview is as follows, you would first want to make an API call to the Payflow endpoint to generate your secure token.  This will also be where you pass over the parameters indicating that you are wanting to set up a recurring payment for Express Checkout.  Then once you get the token back, you will redirect the buyer over to the Payflow hosted pages to complete the payment.  Once this has been completed you can use the bililng agreement id that is created for the customer to create a recurring billing profile.

Comment: Ok I have logged in to the PayPal manager and set up my hosted page and i opt Layout c and publish it. From my page i gave my api call to payflow end point and got my secure token with that i loaded an Iframe to my page and it loads my hosted page. There i have pay with paypal, bill me later and Credit card payment options there. Pay with paypal option doesnt redirect me to any where. The button is in disabled state. How can i set a url to this button. It is mentioned about paypal hosted pages, but i could see 3 layouts from which we can select one. Am I not on the correct understanding?

Comment: I don't want to charge user for the first transaction that only used for getting billing agreement id. Any idea how to do that? Because as I understand, Paypal will try to charge user in the first transaction.